# How to add angular filter to application with routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, route-provider

I'd like to add angular filter working like this one here: https://jsfiddle.net/lukasz9999/9coywzgt/2/

to my template routeProvider code:

```
var app = angular.module("calculatorApplication", []).config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "app/view/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/home"
});

$routeProvider.when("/calculator", {
templateUrl: "app/view/calculator.html",
controller: "CalculatorController"
 });
});

app.controller("HomeController", function () {
});
```

adding
        ['angular.filter']
 to 
    var app = angular.module("calculatorApplication", ['angular.filter']).config(

is breaking application...

Any suggestions how to implement filter to app like this?
Thank you

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you provided there's explicite inclusion of `angular-filter.js` lib:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

If you are not including that in your current app that's porbably the issue here.

Comment: This library is included, but there is en error: like Uncaught Error: Provider [object Object]Filter must define $get factory method. from a8m.contains

Comment: Are you using the same version of angular as in your snippet?

Comment: there was different version but, if its exactly the same the error is:Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/modulerr?p0=calculatorApplicat…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A60)

Comment: It seems that the app still failed to find the module. A bigger snippet of your current code would be nice. The error message is also incomplete, can you post the entire URL to the error docs? 

Based on what I see I can only suggest to once again revise all the dependencies you're loading and also the order (it should be Angular, then angular libs, then your code). Another option is that the version you switched to (1.2.2) now works with filters and the error you are getting now is coming from another piece of your code.